# MC does not apply custom config

Tags: debian, mc

I have a fresh installation of Debian 7. Upon using Midnight Commander I noticed that auto indentation is disabled. 'No problem' I told to myself and changed the `~/.config/mc/ini` file.
Surprisingly that did nothing, as soon as I reopened mc the new `ini`was overwritten with the previous version.
After a little googling I also tried the same with `~/.mc/mc.ini` and `~/.mc/ini` with no results at all.
An `strace` at least showed me that the `~/.config/mc/ini` file is read by mc, but as it seems this file is overwritten somewhat before the read access, which is not traceable in the `strace`.

My next guess was to use a global config file like `/etc/mc/mc.ini` but that changed nothing either.

As suggested below I prevent modification of the ini file via `chattr +i $HOME/.config/mc/ini`. Right now everything works fine. 
Does anyone else experience problems like this? Maybe this is a bug.

Comment: Odd, just tried things out on my system.  Running `GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.12`, does your version differ?   I'm running a custom base of jessie, with most of testing and just a pinch of unstable for flavor.  Perhaps it's been updated. `apt-cache madison mc` shows `4.8.3-10` is available in _stable_, while `4.8.12-1` is available in jessie and unstable.   ChangeLog shows a good number of updates/upgrades.

Comment: The funny thing is, that the same issue occured with mc version `4.8.3-10`. After the first problems with the version installed via aptitude I decided to install the newest version from source, which changed nothing. So I assume it's not about the version, more likely about the way I did it or my system is set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about Midnight Commander itself but it seems like you located the correct config file by using `strace`. If the file is overwritten before it's read maybe you can try locking down the file with the `chattr` command so that it cannot be edited.

```
chattr +i $HOME/.config/mc/ini
```

Comment: Alright Dude you made my day, this is at least a workaround I can live with. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone else experience problems like this? Maybe this is a bug.

Mee too. I was editing `~/.config/mc/ini` with `mcedit`, so <kbd>F2</kbd> would save the file, but apparently on <kbd>F10</kbd> (exit) mcedit would overwrite the file.

In other words the overwrite happens, because of using the editor to edit its own configuration file.

So the solution was to make the change, save <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit instead of <kbd>F10</kbd>.